# ¿Cómo unir dos documentos pdf que se generan con itextsharp? En C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, itextsharp

Buen día.
Estoy tratando de unir dos documentos pdf que estoy generando, ya que cada documento debe tener un footer diferente. Por ejemplo quiero crear una copia del otro con distinto footer en sus paginas. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
public ActionResult genera_report_factura(string empresa, string registros)
    {
        string Path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");
        string error = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] pdf = null;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                int h_inferior = 200;
                using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 25, 25, 235, h_inferior))
                {
                    var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                    pdfWriter.PageEvent = new HeaderFooter();
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
                    table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    table.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    float[] widths = new float[] { 20, 50, 30 };
                    table.SetWidths(widths);
                    Paragraph celda = new Paragraph();

                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                    celda = new Paragraph();
                    celda.Add(new Chunk("PRIMER DOCUMENTO", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    celda.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                    cell = new PdfPCell();
                    cell.Colspan = 3;
                    cell.Border = 0;
                    cell.AddElement(celda);
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                    pdfDoc.Add(table);
                    pdfDoc.Close();

                }
                using (var pdfDoc2 = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 25, 25, solo_fatura, h_inferior + h_cedible))
                {
                    var pdfWriter2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc2, stream);
                    pdfWriter.PageEvent = new EVENTOHEADERDOS();

                    pdfDoc2.Open();//Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto
                    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(3);
                    table2.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                    table2.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    table2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    float[] widths2 = new float[] { 20, 50, 30 };
                    table2.SetWidths(widths2);
                    Paragraph celda2 = new Paragraph();

                    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
                    celda2 = new Paragraph();
                    celda2.Add(new Chunk("SEGUNDO documento", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    celda2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                    cell2 = new PdfPCell();
                    cell2.Colspan = 3;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    cell2.AddElement(celda2);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);
                    pdfDoc2.Add(table2);
                    pdfDoc2.Close();

                }
                pdf = stream.ToArray();
            }
           
            return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path + "wow_error.txt": " + error);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

**Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto**
y justo en la linea donde tengo definido :pdfDoc2.Open();

Probé de esta otra forma, no me sale error, pero lo del pdfDoc2, no escribe o no genera nada:

```
public ActionResult genera_report_factura(string empresa, string registros)
    {
        string Path = Server.MapPath("~/Upload/");
        string error = "";
        try
        {
            byte[] pdf = null;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                int h_inferior = 200;
                using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 25, 25, 235, h_inferior))
                {

                    var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream);
                    pdfWriter.PageEvent = new HeaderFooter();
                    pdfDoc.Open();
                    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
                    table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                    table.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    table.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    float[] widths = new float[] { 20, 50, 30 };
                    table.SetWidths(widths);
                    Paragraph celda = new Paragraph();

                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
                    celda = new Paragraph();
                    celda.Add(new Chunk("PRIMER DOCUMENTO", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    celda.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                    cell = new PdfPCell();
                    cell.Colspan = 3;
                    cell.Border = 0;
                    cell.AddElement(celda);
                    table.AddCell(cell);
                    pdfDoc.Add(table);
                    
                    
                    var pdfDoc2 = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 25, 25, solo_fatura, h_inferior);
                

                    var pdfWriter2 = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc2, stream);
                    pdfWriter.PageEvent = new EVENTOHEADERDOS();

                    pdfDoc2.Open();
                    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(3);
                    table2.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER;
                    table2.WidthPercentage = 100;
                    //table.SpacingBefore = 605f;

                    //0=Left, 1=Centre, 2=Right
                    table2.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
                    float[] widths2 = new float[] { 20, 50, 30 };
                    table2.SetWidths(widths2);
                    Paragraph celda2 = new Paragraph();

                    PdfPCell cell2 = new PdfPCell();
                    celda2 = new Paragraph();
                    celda2.Add(new Chunk("SEGUNDO documento", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 9, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    celda2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
                    cell2 = new PdfPCell();
                    cell2.Colspan = 3;
                    cell2.Border = 0;
                    cell2.AddElement(celda2);
                    table2.AddCell(cell2);
                    pdfDoc2.Add(table2);
                    
                    
                    pdfDoc.Close();
                    //pdfDoc2.Close();//si lo coloco se cae, porque me dice que no se puede cerrar un bloque que ya está cerrado


                }
                

                
                pdf = stream.ToArray();

            }
           
            return File(pdf, "application/pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            error = ex.Message;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Path + "wow_error.txt", linea + ": " + error);
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Si alguien tiene alguna idea, se lo agradecería mucho o algun ejemplo.
Saludos cordiales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucione, para los que necesitan una solución, aquí les dejo un aporte:

```
public ActionResult genera_report_factura(string empresa, string registros)
    {
        byte[] mergedPdf = null;

        List<byte[]> pdf = new List<byte[]>();

        pdf.Add(crear_y_guarda_pdf_factura(empresa, registros, 0));
        pdf.Add(crear_y_guarda_pdf_factura(empresa, registros, 1));


        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (Document document = new Document())
            {
                using (PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, ms))
                {
                    document.Open();

                    for (int i = 0; i < pdf.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf[i]);
                        // loop over the pages in that document
                        int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
                        for (int page = 0; page < n;)
                        {
                            copy.AddPage(copy.GetImportedPage(reader, ++page));
                        }
                    }
                    document.Close();
                }
            }
            mergedPdf = ms.ToArray();
       

        return File(mergedPdf, "application/pdf");

    }
```

La idea es crear los pdf con itexsharp por separado, retornar un byte[] y en la función que los llama almacenarlo en una lista para unirlos.

Saludos, espero que les sirva el ejemplo